How to make ESLint / prettier sort object keys and imports alphabetically on save?
I am currently switching from VSCode, which automatically reorders object keys and imports when I save my JS/React files.
Everything else works, like if certain lines are not indented it'll indent itself. But I can't seem to get it to sort and am not sure which plugin I need to install to achieve this. 
Before save (keys are out of order):
After save  (keys are still out of order, but properly indented):


"I can't seem to get it to sort" - what have you tried?

Vim itself is not involved in anything in your screenshots. Use the issue tracker of whatever plugin(s) that you installed.

Also there is no order in an object.

@Friedrich I just discovered that it works when I use code actions, but that's only if I manually highlight each individual line with a warning. Is there a way to just run code actions for all the lines in a file?

"Is there a way to just run code actions for all the lines in a file?" - there probably is. It depends on whatever plugin you're using.

Removed [tag:blackbox] since there was nothing else pointing to it and no information that I could connect to the question. Feel free to discuss on [meta].

FWIW, this is one of my gripes with lazy: how can you know what to ask when it shoves all this stuff in for you and then doesn’t tell you what they are? Took me an hour to find out what plugin had modified a friend’s command-line to edit in a floating window. Silly… anyway: please [edit] with requested details
